Can a server be fired for a customer walking out in a restaurant
Suppose at a restaurant, a customer leaves without paying the check. The server is either unaware that they left or unable to stop them.
Can the restaurant compel the server to pay for the walkouts? Could they legally fire the server for the walkouts?

I substantially re-wrote your question to mitigate the close reasons. Please review and confirm I didn't change your intent. I strongly recommend you add either a state or country tag to get quality answers.

The place this happens matters a lot. the law in most of the U.S. is materially different from most other developed countries with Western style laws on this point.


Is this policy practice even legal?

Sure. Matter of fact the solution you have in mind, paying for the damages out of your own pocket, is illegal in many countries. In many countries you cannot dock pay for normal damages happening as a normal risk of running business and an employee "docking pay 'voluntarily' because otherwise we would have fired them" is about the same.
I have no idea where you live and whether it would even be legal to pay for the damages out of your own pocket. But even if it were, it is an option the employer does not have to take. They can absolutely discipline you for something you did wrong, and three written warnings until official termination sounds more than fair, even in countries with very protective labor laws.
In some countries (the US being the most famous example) you can be fired for "any reason or no reason at all". Which certainly applies here. Something factual happened and the company blames you for it. They don't even need to. They could fire you for three days of rain. It doesn't need to be your fault.
However, if you live in a country with better labor laws, you may want to ask a lawyer from your juristiction, if written warnings are neccessary to fire you, and if those written warnings you received are technically correct for this purpose. Small business owners don't always get that right, they don't have the money or patience to have their own lawyers.
For example, where I live, they cannot just fire people based on facts happening (like 3 days rain). They have to provide the action they want you to take, and they can only fire you if you fail to take that action. For example the written reprimand could state that you failed to remind the guests that they still have to pay when the left the restaurant. That is your action as employee and if you repeatedly fail to take that action at work that is grounds for termination. However, if a group of MMA champions leaves, you politely remind them and they shove you out of the way, it's the same end result for the business, but you did everything you were told to do as your job. So there would be no grounds for any reprimands there. If the written reprimand stated you'd have to physically keep them from leaving, that might be illegal alltogether and you are not required to do something illegal just because your boss says so.
So bottom line, writing you up and firing you instead of you paying for damages is their decision and probably legal. They don't have to accept your compensation.
Whether their write ups are legally required and/or valid, is highly dependent on your local labor laws. You should see a local lawyer about that.
Independent of the law, ask them what they want you to do to minimize walkouts. Next time, show them you did. Regardless of labor laws, it's easier to do what your employer wants than fighting them through lawyers.

Thank you for your promptness and also for further helping me understand my particular situation.... I'm not sure if I'm allowed to do a follow up question in this thread, but...I work in a theme park, where guests are in the park for the remainder of the day.... Due to traceable documents, these guests would have been easily flagged and made to come forth and forced to pay their bill.... The company just refuses to do so.... That doesn't sit right with me, and I would like to be able to do something about, that, aspect of the walkout I experienced....

Protective labor law (if that even exists in your location) does not care whether there were damages. Well, unless you caused them deliberately. Did you do what your boss wanted and instructed you to do? The only defense against a "no" would be if what your boss wanted was illegal, or if you were not given the means to actually do it. You do what your boss wants you to do, if you don't, you get fired. Damages are mostly irrelevant.

Also, your reasoning amounts to "I failed at my job, but there are other people in the company who could have made up for it without losses". Well, if that isn't the perfect reason why you should be let go... go ask your boss what they want you to do. Then do it. There is no legal right to just not care what your boss wants you to do.

FWIW, the one exception to the general rule in the U.S. in Montana, in which employees can only be fired for cause.
